# Getting Dialogflow webhook path parameters using Actions On Google SDK

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Is there a way to retrieve path parameters setted by Dialogflow fulfillment webhook?
I'm using Node.js actions-on-google SDK in a Google Cloud Function.

My webhook URL is something like this: `https://europe-myexample.cloudfunctions.net/actionHandler/v1`

I need to get the `v1` param to use it in `manageWelcomeIntent` function.

```
const NLGService = require('./services/NLGService.js');
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const app = dialogflow();

exports.actionHandler = app;

app.intent('welcome_intent', NLGService.manageWelcomeIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you e.g. use
`const url = require('url');`, or, even simpler, `req.url`
for finding out your server url and then extracting the param?

Comment: Yes, I can, but i need to retrieve the param v1 into the `manageWelcomeIntent` function to handle it. 

It should be included into the `conv` function param passed to `manageWelcomeIntent` but it is totally handled by the actions-on-google SDK.

Comment: OK, but can you not retrieve v1 during the initialization of your node.js server, then assign it to a global variable that you export, and import that in your `./services/NLGService.js` module? Then it should be accessible in your `manageWelcomeIntent` function.